# What to use as a queue between API and Backend

Tags: .net, database, .net-core, architecture, queue

I have an application that has a .NET Core WebAPI and a .NET Core Console App. Both need to access the queue (which contains messages) to handle them or to store new messages.

A queue item should have a state.

Normally, the WebAPI will store new messages in the queue, but can also read the messages from the queue.
The Backend will take the messages from the queue and do a lot of processing with each message and change a state of a queue item.

- What should I use as a queue ?
- Is it a good idea to use a database as a queue ?

I don't want to use RabbitMQ or MSMQ.

Thank you!

Comment: You can build your own database-driven queuing system if you want, but I see no reason to reinvent the wheel.  Why do you want to build your own version of RabbitMQ or MSMQ when you can just use what's available already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I use as a queue ?

It depends on your requirements. There are many message queue available right now.
I mention [Nats](https://nats.io/) who is member of Cloud Native Computing Foundation and have an easy deployment. But you can't make a proper software selection without you haven't clear requirements.

> Is it a good idea to use a database as a queue ?

Not at all. Database is not a message queue. Maybe don't you need a message queue but just a place to store your data and pick up them later?

[This](https://aws.amazon.com/it/message-queue/) is how AWS define a message queue.

> I don't want to use RabbitMQ or MSMQ.

I wonder to know why these are not ok for you...